# i want to hit the API but it is not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

controller **PagesController**

```
public function index()
{
     $client = new Client();
     $hospital_id = 37;
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://vph.com/api/GetService'.$hospital_id,[
    'form_params' => [
        'body'=>$hospital_id
         ]

]);
```

i want to api hit but is not working

**ERROR**

```
Client error: `POST http://vpshealth.com/api/GetServiceList37` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: <html> <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center> <hr> (truncated...)
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI5JY.png)

Comment: why are you appending `$hospital_id`?

Comment: What are your routes?

Comment: vph.com, vpshealth.com? Which is it?

Comment: This means that method doesn't exists, can you please check the method along with the Request type first?

Comment: The URLs in your code and the error message don't match. Is there a redirect?

Answer (score 1):

missing **/** in the URL

url should be **http://vph.com/api/GetService/'.$hospital_id**

```
public function index()
{
     $client = new Client();
     $hospital_id = 37;
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://vph.com/api/GetService/'.$hospital_id,[
    'form_params' => [
        'body'=>$hospital_id
         ]

]);
```

Comment: all are changes is done yes URL is missing but error is same

Comment: any idea how to hit the api in laravel

Comment: what is the  version ?

Comment: i am using the laravel5.6 i am allready used the GuzzleHttp but it is not working

Comment: I think the problem is in the API URL. Make sure that you are using the correct URL. You can check that using a REST Client like "Postman"

Comment: friend do you know how to hit the API for any example

Comment: thanks thamira, but sorry friends i cann't understand frnd any other souce code will provide me. please help me bro

Comment: $client = new Client();       $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

Answer (score 0):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $hospital_id = 37;

    $response = $client->request("POST", "http://vpshealth.com/api/GetServiceList?hospital_id=".$hospital_id,
        [
            'json'=>['body'=>$hospital_id]
            ]);
    $data=$response->getbody();
    $data=json_decode($data);
    dd($data);
```

**solve**